# How to simulate different network scenarios ? (in Java)

Tags: java, networking

I’m building a client server application that should operate 24/7. The applications is designate to detect network failures (using a heart beating) and reconnect to the server asap.

The first test that I made is just stopping the client or the server and then starting again and everything works fine. I’m wondering if there is any tools that can help me simulate congestion, delays or more realistic problem than just unplugging my Ethernet cable.

Answer (score 3):

Does the app use plain tcp sockets?  Or does it use HTTP/HTTPS?  If its HTTP based, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/) (as well as some other proxy servers) has the capability of simulating slow connection speeds, albeit at the expense of being windows only.

Alternatively, I've had good experiences with tools like [Apache TCPMon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/) and its [ilk](https://tcpmon.dev.java.net/).  These can simulate congestion and line breaks fairly well, although in my experience, you will still end up finding new and interesting failure modes in the real world.

Comment: Tks for your response!. We are using JMS over bisockets

Answer (score 1):

[Sniffy](http://sniffy.io/) allows you to [block outgoing network connections](http://sniffy.io/docs/latest/#_non_servlet_applications) in your Java applications - it will throw a `ConnectException` whenever you try to establish a new connection to restricted host.

Just add `-javaagent:sniffy.jar=5559` to your JVM arguments and point your browser to `localhost:5559` - it will open a web page with all discovered connections to downstream systems and controls to disable certain connections.

[image: Sniffy connections console]

Currently (as of version 3.1.3) it only supports no-connectivity scenarios, but adding latency is on the road map.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of Sniffy*